# Serial Port component from Visual Basic 6 to .NET Framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration

So, I'm trying to port a Visual Basic 6 software into the new dot NET.

My software is using the serial port via the code

```
My_form.Ser_port.Settings = "38400,n,8,1"
My_form.Ser_port.RThreshold = 1
If My_form.Ser_port.PortOpen = False Then
    My_form.Ser_port.PortOpen = True
End If
```

Clearly, it seems that dot NET doesn't have such settings.

I have correctly imported the SerialPort1 componetn and I can see it on the bottom of my working area but, how can I open/Close and set the parameters as VB6? I see I can set the BaudRate, RecievedByesThreshold but there's no PortOpen option.

Does it opens automatically?

Comment: I suggest to not use the the VB6 COM component, but use .NET's native [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class instead.

Comment: Try using the `.PortName` property.  Here's a link to an [MSDN article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d3c8089-215c-4aab-a644-edb607206053/serial-port-from-vb6-to-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral).

Answer (score 1):

In your code (VB6) SerialPort.PortOpen is a property:

```
SerialPort.PortOpen=True or False
```

But in VB.NET it is not property, it is a sub of the component:

You have to call SerialPort.Open() or SerialPort.Close(). You can also get property if it's port open or no: SerialPort.IsOpen=True or False.

Here is an example how to work with serial port in VB.Net. If you worked with VS2022 you have to first install NuGet Package named System.IO.Ports.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim SP As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    With SP
        .PortName = "COM1" 
        .BaudRate = 1200
        .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
        .DataBits = 8
        .StopBits = 1
    End With
  End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
If SP.IsOpen Then
Exit Sub
Else
SP.Open()
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
If SP.IsOpen Then
SP.Close()
End If
End Sub
End Class
```